# Carousel Controls Outside of Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a carousel with the control arrows outside of it but no matter what I try the arrows won't get out. If I put the controls code outside the carousel it works but they don't align properly at the sides of the carousel.

Here is the code of the controls on the HTML:

```
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselControles" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev bi bi-chevron-left font-mainColor-s1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselControles" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next bi bi-chevron-right font-mainColor-s1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
#myCarousel {
  margin-left: 50px; 
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.carousel-control {
    top: 50%;
  margin: 50px;
}

.carousel-control-prev {
  margin-left: -25px;
}

.carousel-control.next {
  margin-right: -25px;
}
```

This is how I want it to be:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9FRv.jpg)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.carousel-control {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50px, -50px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**This** `code` will position the arrows container in the middle of the carousel, And position the arrows on each edge of the carousel

**1-Note:** You can position the arrows  nearest to each other by reducing the width

**2-Note:** If the container position was not in the right position you can edit it by changing the values of this code: `transform: translate(-50px, -50px);` it depends on which axis you want