# Bootstrap carousel content doesn't appear between arrows

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, bootstrap-5

I've encountered this issue while trying to add a carousel element to my project. The result of my code is a working carousel; the arrows work just fine and if I add an autoplay option it also works. However, the content itself is NOT between the arrows.

First, I've included the following lines of code in the header section for bootstrap, which I downloaded via npm:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/main.css">
    <script src="./node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Then, I added the elements for the carousel exactly like the one in the bootstrap docs:

```
            <div id="projectsCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade carousel-dark">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active"><h3>hello</h3></div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">2</div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">3</div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">4</div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">5</div>
                </div>
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#projectsCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#projectsCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
```

As aforementioned, the content itself is NOT between the arrows.

[image]

If anyone can help me figure out why this happens I would be so thankful for them!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="projectsCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade carousel-dark">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <h3>hello</h3>
    </div>
    
    <div class="carousel-item">2</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">3</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">4</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">5</div>
  </div>
  
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#projectsCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#projectsCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content is not *supposed* to be between the arrows. If you look at [the demo](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/carousel/#basic-examples) with your browser's inspector you'll see that the controls lay over the content. The content sits tight to the left edge of the container, whatever that may be. The control button is also tight to the left (positioned absolutely), but it has some padding which makes it appear shifted inward.

Either apply [padding](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding) to your content or use CSS to shift the controls. `translateX()` might work well. See [Carousel Controls Outside of Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69983028/carousel-controls-outside-of-carousel).

Comment: I guess I was expecting the carousel content to be auto-centered, so I thought I was doing something wrong for that to not happen. Anyways, I did try to center the content via CSS and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think carousel-inner taking full width and align item to left so make carousel-inner display-flex (d-flex),justify-content-center,align-item-center.If not word try to add it in carousel-item also.